# display count in textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple problem. I have a table in dataset designer that have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(Sex) AS Male, COUNT(Sex) AS Female
FROM tblPersonalInfo
```

can you please show me how to display the male and female count in 2 textboxes? and can you please check if my query is correct? i'm a newbie in visual studio c# 2010.

form my previous projects, i use these to retrieve data from database and display in textbox.

```
public MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblPositionDataTable GetPositionData(string data)
        {
            MAINDATABASEDataSetTableAdapters.tblPositionTableAdapter ReturnPosition =  new MAINDATABASEDataSetTableAdapters.tblPositionTableAdapter();
            return ReturnPosition.GetDataByPosition(this.txtSearch.Text.Trim());

        }

}
 private void btnCompleteSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                    MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblPositionDataTable GetPositionCommand1 = GetPositionData(this.txtSearch.Text);
                    MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblPositionRow GetPositionCommand2 = (MAINDATABASEDataSet.tblPositionRow)GetPositionCommand1.Rows[0];
                    this.txtMainPosition.Text = GetPositionCommand2.Position.ToString();


            }
```

and i use this query:

```
SELECT   Position  
FROM     tblPosition
WHERE    (ID = @IDMain)
```

Comment: I can be wrong since I don't have your db schema. But I think the query should be something like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) from tblPersonalInfo GROUP BY SEX`

Comment: It is better you can check your query's integrity by yourself, and if you have any problem, you can just ask that specific portion with your thinking.

Comment: i just want to display the male and female count in 2 textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code or background it's impossible to answer properly but as it stands your query will produce the same count for Male as for Female. to count just the males you would need something like

```
SELECT COUNT(Sex) AS Male,
FROM tblPersonalInfo
WHERE Sex = 'Male'
```

and then a second query for female. Or else

```
SELECT COUNT(Sex)
FROM tblPeroncalInfo
GROUP BY Sex
```

Or if you really need them as spearate columns:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = 'Male' 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = 'Female' 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female
FROM tblPersonalInfo
```

Comment: my only problem is how can i display the result of the count in a textbox. i have an example above on how i display my other queries in a textbox.

Comment: @eman If you are able to display a query in a text box, then why not just create two queries (i.e. my first example), one for the count of males and one for the count of females. And then proceed exactly as you have before.

Comment: thnx for the query, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like

```
SELECT COUNT(Sex) from tblPersonalInfo GROUP BY SEX
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(sex) FROM tblPersonalInfo WHERE sex = 'male'

int maleCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScaler();

SELECT COUNT(sex) FROM tblPersonalInfo WHERE sex = 'female'

int femaleCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScaler();
```

You can show the count in two text boxes as

```
textBoxMale.text = maleCount.ToString();
textBoxFemale.text = femaleCount.Tostring();
```